Scikit-learn estimator that accepts non array-like input
I am developing a scikit-learn estimator, the documentation states that the input "X" for the .fit() method should be an "array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)".
However, my estimator takes as input a list of objects (nx Graphs).
What is the best practice to pass the list as input to the fit() method?
In the following implementation, when running "check_estimator()" (used in sklearn to validate a new Estimator) the estimator passes only 5 test out of 30 because my class throws an error when X is a numpy array and not a list
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
import networkx as nx
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
import numpy as np

class MyEstimator(BaseEstimator):

    def _validate_data(
            self,
            X="no_validation",
            y="no_validation"):

        if not np.array_equal(X, "no_validation"):
            assert isinstance(X, list) and all(isinstance(item, nx.Graph) for item in X)
        if not np.array_equal(X, "no_validation") and not np.array_equal(y,"no_validation"):
            return X, y
        elif not np.array_equal(X, "no_validation"):
            return X
        elif not np.array_equal(y, "no_validation"):
            return y

    def fit(self, X: list[nx.Graph], y):
            self._validate_data(X,y)
            self.is_fitted_ = True
            return self

    def predict(self, X):
        check_is_fitted(self)
        X = self._validate_data(X=X)
        return np.ones(len(X), dtype=np.int64)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import check_estimator

    check_estimator = check_estimator(MyEstimator())
                    


Can you insert a reproducible example? What is "TemplateEstimator"? Is it a refuse for "MyEstimator"? If it is so, a clean solution could be using the tolist method from numpy to have the list from a numpy array.

I edited out TemplateEstimator, thank you. However my problem is that I want this class to pass the scikit tests contained in "check_estimator()". However when running the tests I have an input of a numpy matrix which is not something my algorithm is supposed to handle since the expected input is a list of networkx Graphs. So I wonder if there is a way to make this class Scikit compatible.

What does the numpy matrix contain? As you say in your question, you need to pass a list instead of a numpy array. So, you can create a custom function that takes a numpy matrix as input and returns the correct list. You can insert a condition to call this function when the input is a numpy array, for example.

Sorry there is some confusion here:
-My algorithm takes in input a list of nx graphs, for the purpose of this example one can think as a list of objects.
-The function "check_estimator" from the scikit library runs some test to check that the class is compatible with the scikit API. However the test that it runs give as input np.arrays with which my algorithm can not work with.
So I wonder if there is a way around to make my algorithm compatible with the scikit API while still accepting only list of nx Graphs.

I don't think passing check_estimator is exactly the same as "being fully compatible with the sklearn API," and you shouldn't expect a custom estimator that fits on graphs to pass most of those checks.  That said, there are the sklearn text transformers that expect 1D input, so maybe by tagging appropriately most of the irrelevant checks can be skipped?

This is a good news for me. Do you have any idea where to look for the proper tagging, I never worked with it.

I will insert here a simple example. myFunc expects a list, but you give a numpy array. So, you can just insert a control if it is a numpy array instance. If it is, you convert the array X to a list. This minimal code will not produce an assertion error also if you pass a numpy array as a parameter.
import numpy as np

def myFunc(X):
    if isinstance(X, np.ndarray):
      X = X.tolist()
        
    assert isinstance(X, list), "Not list type"
    print(type(X))
    
    
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

myFunc(a)


An np.array does not contain nx.Graphs. I can not convert a np.array to a list of nx Graphs.

Then, what does it contain the np.array? I suppose that processing a nx.Graphs is essential for your code, but your "What is the best practice to pass the list as input to the fit() method?" is quite confusing, in my humble opinion.
